# How do I split an array into smaller arrays bsaed on a condition?

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings

```
2.4.0 :007 > arr = ["a", "b", "g", "e", "f", "i"]
 => ["a", "b", "g", "e", "f", "h", "i"]
```

How do I split my array into smaller arrays based on a condition?  I have a function -- "contains_vowel," which returns true if a string contains "a", "e", "i", "o", or "u".  How would I take an array of strings and split it into smaller arrays, using a divider function of "contains_vowel"?  That is, for the above, the resulting array of smaller arrays would be

```
[["a"], ["b", "g"], ["e"], ["f", "h"], ["i"]]
```

If an element of the larger array satisfies the condition, it would become an array of one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more way to skin a cat

```
def contains_vowel(v) 
   v.count("aeiou") > 0
end 
def split_by_substring_with_vowels(arr)
  arr.chunk_while do |before,after|
    !contains_vowel(before) & !contains_vowel(after)
  end.to_a
end
split_by_substring_with_vowels(arr)
#=> [["a"], ["b", "g"], ["e"], ["f", "h"], ["i"]]
```

What it does:

- passes each consecutive 2 elements
- splits when either of them contain vowels

Example with your other `Array`

```
arr = ["1)", "dwr", "lyn,", "18,", "bbe"]
split_by_substring_with_vowels(arr)
#=> [["1)", "dwr", "lyn,", "18,"], ["bbe"]]
```

Further example: (if you want vowel containing elements in succession to stay in the same group)

```
def split_by_substring_with_vowels(arr)
  arr.chunk_while do |before,after|
    v_before,v_after = contains_vowel(before),contains_vowel(after)
    (!v_before & !v_after) ^ (v_before & v_after)
  end.to_a
end

arr = ["1)", "dwr", "lyn,", "18,", "bbe", "re", "rr", "aa", "ee"]
split_by_substring_with_vowels(arr)
#=> [["1)", "dwr", "lyn,", "18,"], ["bbe", "re"], ["rr"], ["aa", "ee"]]
```

This checks if before and after are both not vowels *Or* if they both are vowels

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = ["a", "b", "g", "e", "f", "i"]

r = /[aeiou]/
arr.slice_when { |a,b| a.match?(r) ^ b.match?(r) }.to_a
   => [["a"], ["b", "g"], ["e"], ["f"], ["i"]]
```

[String#match?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. For earlier versions you could use (for example) `!!(b =~ r)`, where `!!` converts a truthy/falsy value to `true`/`false`. That converstion is needed because the XOR operator `^` serves double-duty: it's a logical XOR when `a` and `b` in `a^b` are `true`, `false` or `nil`, and a bit-wise XOR when the operands are integers, such as `2^6 #=> 4` (`2.to_s(2) #=> "10"; 6.to_s(2) #=> "110"; 4.to_s(2) #=> "100"`).

Comment: or using the OP's function: `arr.slice_when{|a,b| contains_vowel(a) ^ contains_vowel(b)}.to_a`

Comment: @Mark, ...or a proc, but I did it this way just for variety.

Comment: This. `XOR` with `match` is the way to go.

Comment: Might note this is for `>= 2.4` and technically fails this condition *"If an element of the larger array satisfies the condition, it would become an array of one element."* Although I am not certain that is actually the intention

Answer (score 1):

```
contains_vowel = ->(str) { !(str.split('') & %w|a e i o u|).empty? }

_, result = ["a", "b", "g", "e", "f", "h", "i"].
                 each_with_object([false, []]) do |e, acc|
   cv, acc[0] = acc[0], contains_vowel.(e)
   cv ^ acc.first ? acc.last << [e] : (acc.last[-1] ||= []) << e
end
result
#⇒ [["a"], ["b", "g"], ["e"], ["f", "h"], ["i"]]
```

What we do here:

1. `contains_vowel` is a lambda to check whether the string contains a vowel or not.
2. we reduce the input array, collecting the last value (contained the previously handled string the vowel or not,) and the `result`.
3. `cv ^ acc.first` checks whether it was a flip-flop of vowel on the last step.

   1. whether is was, we append a new array to the result
   2. whether is was not, we append the string to the last array in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I might use [`chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) which splits an array everytime the value of its block changes. Chunk returns a list of `[block_value, [elements]]` pairs, I used `.map(&:last)` to only get the sub-lists of elements.

```
arr = ["a", "b", "g", "e", "f", "h", "i"]

def vowel?(x); %w(a e i o u).include?(x); end

arr.chunk{|x| vowel?(x)}.map(&:last)

=> [["a"], ["b", "g"], ["e"], ["f", "h"], ["i"]]
```

Comment: Not sure if I cut and pasted osmething wrong, but if my array is ["1)", "dwr", "lyn,", "18,", "bbe"], applying your logic produces [["1)", "dwr", "lyn,", "18,", "bbe"]], but it shoudl be two arrays -- [["1)", "dwr", "lyn,", "18,"], ["bbe"]] since only one element in my array contains a vowel (should split there producing two arrays)

Comment: My `vowel?` function won't work on those examples. What if you use the one you wrote before?